# To check whether $ 10^{c} \frac{N}{e} > (N!)^{\frac{1}{N}} > \frac{N}{e}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is the following true or false for $N\geq 3$?

$\log N - \log e + c >\frac{\log N!}{N}> \log N - \log{e}$ for some $ c< \log e$ where the logarithm is w.r.t. base $10.$

Calculating some values suggest it should be true. But if it is true, is there any elementary way by which we can show this.

In fact if we take the log out, I am getting ,
$ 10^{c} \frac{N}{e} > (N!)^{\frac{1}{N}} > \frac{N}{e}$ but I can't see whether it is true for all $N\geq 3$ and for some $c< \log e$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key ingredient for your question is [this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: @rtybase I think he wants the result to hold for all N > 3, not only for "big enough" N.

Comment: @Ant that's why I wrote "key ingredient", not "answer"!

Comment: @Ant you are correct

Comment: Why not use Sterling's approximation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that

$$e\left(\frac ne\right)^n \le n! \le en\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

Which is equivalent to

$$e^{1/n} \frac ne \le n!^{1/n} \le (en)^{1/n} \frac ne$$

For the left part of the inequality; since $e^{1/n} > 1$, $$n!^{1/n}  \ge e^{1/n} \frac ne > \frac ne$$

For the right part of the inequality, focus on the $(en)^{1/n}$. This function as a maximum at $n=1$, where it attains the value of $e$. After this point it is decreasing. Therefore, for $n > 3$, the function is lower than $e$, which means that you can find a $c$ close enough to $\log e$ such that $10^c >(en)^{1/n}$ for all $n > 3$

---

The following proof of the first inequality is lifted from the [italian wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approssimazione_di_Stirling) on the Stirling approximation.

Let $n$ be an integer. Then

$$\ln n! = \sum_{k = 1}^n \ln k = \sum_{k = 1}^n k\ln k - \sum_{k = 1}^n (k - 1)\ln k $$

$$= n \ln n  - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k \left[\ln(k + 1) - \ln k \right] =  n \ln n  - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} k \int_{k}^{k + 1} \frac{dt}{t}$$

$$= n \ln n  - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \int_{k}^{k + 1} \frac{ \lfloor t \rfloor dt}{t} = n \ln n  - \int_{1}^{n} \frac{ \lfloor t \rfloor dt}{t} =  n \ln n  - (n-1) + \int_{1}^{n} \frac{ \{ t \} dt}{t},$$

where  $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\left \{ x \right \}$ are the integer part and the fractional part of $x$, respectively.

This implies
$$n \ln n - (n-1) \leq \ln n! \leq n \ln n - (n-1) + \ln n$$

and after exponentiating you'll find
$$ e \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \leq n! \leq e n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$

Comment: But how did you get the first line?

Comment: @mathisfun added the derivation

Comment: Here $c=\log_{10} e$ also works. Am I correct?

Comment: Such an excellent proof , +1. If you have time kindly go through my previous post about positivity of some function.

Comment: I have addressed your comments. Sure, $c = \log_{10} e$ also works; the bigger $c$ is, the better

Answer (score 1):

Following the way you started, using [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Some_specific_types_of_Riemann_sums) ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586096/prove-sum-limitsn-1-i-1-i-ln-i-leq-fracn22-ln-n-fracn24/3586163#3586163) is another example) and considering that $\color{green}{f(x)=\ln{x}}$ is monotone increasing
$$ 10^{c} \cdot\frac{N}{e} > (N!)^{\frac{1}{N}} > \frac{N}{e} \iff\\
c\ln{10}+\color{blue}{\ln{N}-1}>
\color{red}{\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k}\right)}>
\color{blue}{\ln{N}-1}$$

However ([Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Some_specific_types_of_Riemann_sums))
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^N \ln{k} 
= \sum\limits_{k=2}^N \color{green}{f(k)}\cdot (k+1-k)\leq 
\int\limits_{2}^{N+1} \color{green}{f(x)}dx=
x(\ln{x}-1)\Big |_{2}^{N+1}=\\
(N+1)(\ln{(N+1)}-1)-2(\ln{2}-1)$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^N \ln{k} 
= \sum\limits_{k=2}^N \color{green}{f(k)}\cdot (k-(k-1))\geq 
\int\limits_{1}^{N} \color{green}{f(x)}dx=
x(\ln{x}-1)\Big |_{1}^{N}=\\
N(\ln{N}-1)+1$$

So
$$\ln{N}-1+\frac{1}{N}\leq
\color{red}{\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k}\right)}
\leq\frac{N+1}{N}(\ln{(N+1)}-1)-\frac{2(\ln{2}-1)}{N}$$
One part becomes easy to see
$$\color{blue}{\ln{N}-1}<\ln{N}-1+\frac{1}{N}\leq
\color{red}{\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k}\right)}$$
The other
$$\color{red}{\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \ln{k}\right)}
\leq\frac{N+1}{N}(\ln{(N+1)}-1)-\frac{2(\ln{2}-1)}{N}=\\
\ln{(N+1)}-1+\frac{\ln{(N+1)}-1}{N}-\frac{2(\ln{2}-1)}{N}=\\
\color{blue}{\ln{N}-1}+\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)}+\frac{\ln{(N+1)}-1}{N}-\frac{2(\ln{2}-1)}{N}$$
What is left [to show](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28ln%281%2B1%2FN%29%2B%28ln%28N%2B1%29-1%29%2FN-%282%28ln%282%29-1%29%29%2FN%29%2Fln%2810%29) is
$$\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)}+\frac{\ln{(N+1)}-1}{N}-\frac{2(\ln{2}-1)}{N}=\\
\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^N}+\ln{(N+1)}-2\ln{2}+1}{N}<\\
\frac{1+\ln{(N+1)}-2\ln{2}+1}{N}<
\frac{\ln{(N+1)}+0.62}{N}<
c\ln{10}$$
Since $\ln{10}>2$, any $c$ satisfying
$$\frac{\ln{(N+1)}+0.62}{2N}\leq c$$
will do. Function $\frac{\ln{(x+1)}+0.62}{2x}$ is decreasing (check the 1st derivative), thus we can take (for $x=1$)
$$c= \frac{\ln{2}+0.62}{2}\approx 0.65657...<1=\ln{e}$$