# Proof that $\log n! = n \log n - n + O(\log n)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

This is from Cameron's Combinatorics text (Theorem 3.6.1). His given proof is a one liner

$n \log n - n + 1 \leq \log n! \leq n \log n- n + (\log(n + 1) + 2 - \log 2)$

He doesn't explain himself. Where exactly is he pulling these inequalities from?

Comment: Maybe not how he proved it but Stirling's approximation gives$$\log{(n!)}-n\log{(n)}+n\sim\frac12\log{(2\pi)}+\frac12\log{(x)}$$

Comment: Consider $\log n!=\log 1 + \log 2 + ... \log n$ as an approximation to a Riemann integral

Comment: I'm sure he is proving a weak form of Stirling by naive means. @PeterForeman

Comment: Try using  Riemann sums, as per [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717866/to-check-whether-10c-fracne-n-frac1n-fracne/3717957#3717957).

Comment: I located my copy of the book. Cameron proves this on the next page ....

Comment: Yeah, I spent quite some time staring at just that page before giving up and reading the rest. I blame his poor formatting and presentation

Answer (score 1):

He is comparing $\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k$ with $\int_1^n\log x\,dx$. Certainly
$$I=\int_1^n\log x\,dx=n\log n-n+1\le\sum_{k=2}^n\log k=\log n!$$
since $\log x\le\log k$ on the interval $[k-1,k]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Stirling's approximation for the factorial.

$\ln n! = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(n) \ge \int_{1}^{n} \ln(x) \ dx = n\ln n - n + 1$

Thus, $\ln n! \ge n\ln n - n + 1$

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 0):

Playing around.

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n!)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_1^k \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\int_{j}^{j+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n \int_{j}^{j+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(n-j) \int_{j}^{j+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}n\int_{j}^{j+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j \int_{j}^{j+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=n\int_{1}^{n} \dfrac{dt}{t}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln(1+1/j)\\
&=n\ln(n)-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln(1+1/j)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $f(n) = n\ln(n)-\ln(n!)$,
since $x-x^2/2 < \ln(1+x) < x$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln(1+1/j)\\
&<\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(1/j)\\
&=n-1\\
\text{and}\\
f(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln(1+1/j)\\
&>\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(\frac1{j}-\frac1{2j^2})\\
&=n-1-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2j}\\
&>n-1-\frac12\ln(n)\\
\end{array}
$